# Redo logfiles are missing on Oracle database 11g manual standby database

Tags: oracle

Log files are missing on my standby database server, please help to re create it. My standby database was created manual method.

[image][image]

I need to get the missing redo logfiles back on standby database.

Answer (score 0):

They will be created when you open the standby database. Online redo log files are not used in a standby (manual or Data Guard) database in MOUNT stage.

Answer (score 0):

My standby database is opened read only mode but online redo log has not created, I mean physical files are missing on the server in OS level. If I check on DB side it’s showing logically files are associated in database.

Comment: And why do you think you need those files? Online redo log files are not used in read only mode.

Answer (score -1):

try running this command on standby -

ALTER DATABASE CLEAR LOGFILE GROUP 1;

then check if files are created for group 1. follow same for other groups as well